# How to draw a bar range plot with matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization

I am trying to create a bar range plot with a temporal x-axis with matplotlib. As an example see the following :

[image: plot]

As far as I see, Matplotlib doesn't directly support this kind of plot.
What is the best way to achieve this?

Maybe its possible to adjust a `boxplot` or a `fill_between` plot?

Comment: It should be possible with a `fill_between` plot, but will take some manual fiddling and finding a sensible (default) value for the bar width. Might look into it later, but don't have time now

Comment: This is called a [`bar`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html) plot in matplotlib.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just pass the `bottom` parameter to [`bar`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html), e.g:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(10)
y_bot = np.linspace(30, 50, 10)
y_dif = np.linspace(10, 5, 10)

plt.bar(x, y_dif, bottom=y_bot)
```

Comment: @SamMason no problem :)  I noticed the import mismatch when trying out your answer for myself